# Kivy application throwing context_intructions.so error on run

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to set up a base kivy app to check if everything is working properly, I have ironed out most issues however I'm getting this one issue whenever I try to run an example application:

`python quit unexpectedly using the context_intructions.so plug-in`

This error shows once I run `python project.py`

The example code I used to check everything can be seen below, but even using the kivy supplied base project code gives me the same error.

```
import kivy  # importing main package
from kivy.app import App  # required base class for your app.
from kivy.uix.label import Label  # uix element that will hold text
kivy.require("1.10.1")  # make sure people running py file have right version

# Our simple app. NameApp  convention matters here. Kivy
# uses some magic here, so make sure you leave the App bit in there!
class EpicApp(App):
    # This is your "initialize" for the root wiget
    def build(self):
        # Creates that label which will just hold text.
        return Label(text="Hey there!")


# Run the app.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    EpicApp().run()
```

I am somewhat concerned about having to use `python projectname.py` to run my kivy app but I read if pip/homebrew is used (which I did) it can be run with `python`. I also don't seem to be able to find anything online where others have had this issue.

***EDIT***
Thought I'd just add that removing everything but `import kivy` is no problem but as soon as I import something i.e. `kivy.app` it errors..

Error Details:

```
Process:               Python [20084]
Path:                  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               2.7.10 (2.7.10)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [18315]
Responsible:           Python [20084]
User ID:               501

PlugIn Path:             /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kivy/graphics/context_instructions.so
PlugIn Identifier:       context_instructions.so
PlugIn Version:          ??? (???)

Date/Time:             2019-04-27 12:35:04.877 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.4 (18E226)
```

Comment: I've never seen this particular error before, can you post the full log? Is there nothing else in it at all? How did you install Kivy, and what operating system are you using?

Comment: Hey, I am using ios, I followed the following set up:(Using Homebrew and Pip section) https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-osx.html , I have attached the error to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so turns out i was being an idiot, I had to use `kivy3 main.py` instead of `kivy main.py`...  make sure your dependancies are correct folks...